# Populate column based on another column in R

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how to populate the NA cells in the user-type column based on the user column. Would appreciate any help, thank you.

| user | user_type |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | emp |
| 124 | man |
| 125 | man |
| 124 | NA |
| 123 | NA |
| 125 | NA |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could combine `group_by` and `fill`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(user) %>% 
  fill(user_type, .direction = "down")
```

```
   user user_type
  <int> <chr>    
1   123 emp      
2   124 man      
3   125 man      
4   124 man      
5   123 emp      
6   125 man
```